# What does $\stackrel{\mathcal L}{=} $ mean?

Tags: probability, notation

I guess

$ A \stackrel{\mathcal L}{=} B $

means $A$ and $B$ hand side has the same probability distribution.  Is that right?

Comment: The next time you ask about notation, please don't forget to mention the book/paper/whatever you were reading when you saw this.

Comment: It's an unpublished book.  But I will remember your suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct.  $A$ and $B$ are "equal in law" (thus the letter L), that is $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution.